# Acumulative variable with JasperReports

Tags: java, variables, jasper-reports, ireport

I need to do a sum acumulative in a column of my report. I retrieve a value from the database and I fill the other columns with some mathematical operation with this value. 
The last column must be the sum and in every row it must to sum the above value also.
For example:

```
DATA-DB  | COLUMN_1 (A)       |    COLUMN_2 (B)      |       COLUMN-3 (C)          |          COLUMN-4 (D)      |    

  2000   |     (2000/2)       |   (2000 *60)/365     |     column_1 + column_2     |    column_1 + column_2     |      D1   
  1500   |      (1500/2)      |    (1500*60)/365     |     column_1 + column_2     |    column_1 + column_2 +D1 |      D2   
  3000   |      (3000/2)      |    (3000*60)/365     |     column_1 + column_2     |    column_1 + column_2 +D2 |      D3
```

How can I do that? I dont find the way. 
I had tried some variables and things similar to :
 `$V{var1}= $V{var1}+$V{TOC}` and I get errors.

I using the `iReport 4.0`. 
Please let me know if that is possible in `iReport`?

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward and standard way to do something like this would be to:

1. Create three new variables. Call them `half`, `times60by365` and `sum`.
2. Go to their properties and define the **Variable Class** to be `java.lang.Integer` or `Double`, which will allow you to use them for arithmetic operations.
3. Change their **Variable Expression** properties to `$F{amount}/2` for `half`, `$F{amount}*60/365` for `times60by365` and `$V{half} + $V{times60by365}` for `sum`
4. Drag them to the detail line

PS: iReport release: 4.0.1 is available since yesterday!